# Шаблон ввода телефона

Tags: jquery, inputmask

Использую такую библиотеку jquery.inputmask.bundle.js
Подскажите, почему при отправки формы не работает required и в placeholder вставляется +7 (32_) ..., а не +7 ()....?

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" minlength="6"  required>

$("input[name='phone']").inputmask("+7 (999) 999 99 99", {
      alias: 'phonebe',
      clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
      onBeforeMask: function (value, opts) {
        var processedValue = value.replace(/^0/g, "");
        if (processedValue.indexOf("32") > 1 ||     processedValue.indexOf("32") == -1) {
          processedValue = "32" + processedValue;
        }

        return processedValue;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

частично решил проблему с required путём убирания clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,

Answer (score 1):

Вставляется 32 потому что у вас в методе `onBeforeMask` прописано:

```
if (processedValue.indexOf("32") > 1 ||     processedValue.indexOf("32") == -1) {
          processedValue = "32" + processedValue;
        }
```

Уберите это условие и всё.
По поводу `required` в документации нет ничего по моему, это надо проверять не с помощью этой библиотеки, а на стороне бекенда или другой JS библиотеки.